# MD5 using Groovy in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, md5, soapui

I created a test case which contains parameters that consist of key and value.
I need to take all those parameters in an alphabetic order, and then create a MD5 hash value which i will pass to one of the parameters of this test.

Any suggestions? i looked in google and cannot find anything helpful.
Thanks ahead!

Comment: can you show details about parameters or screen shot? are you talking about test case properties? is the issue creating md5 or accessing the properties?

Comment: The issue is how i access the parameters, appending them in an alphabetic order and also between each key=value i need to add &. For some reason i am not able to add screenshots.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by parameters?

Comment: i mean properties

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the SoapUI's test case properties using a Groovy Script test step as given below.

```
def map = context.testCase.properties.keySet().inject([:]){map, key ->  map[key] = context.testCase.getPropertyValue(key); map }  
map.each { key, value ->     log.info "Property name : ${key} and value : ${value}" }
```

Since you have the properties in map / key=value  format, you should able to achieve what you are looking for.

Regarding md5 generation Refer [here](https://gist.github.com/ikarius/299062/85b6540c99878f50f082aaee236ef15fc78e527c)

> import java.security.MessageDigest
>
> def generateMD5_A(String s){
>       MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(s.bytes).encodeHex().toString()
>   }

Comment: BTW is there a way to transfer all properties into a test? or upload a list of properties directly into a test?

Comment: what do you mean by that? did not understand? Have you tried that in first place?

Comment: there is an option to upload a properties file into a properties testStep. Afterwards i created a test, and i want to load all those properties into the test self. I did it manually one by one at first.

Comment: Is above answer solves your original post ? If not please edit your question to have correct details please?

Comment: regarding your solution, i am getting empty result {}. how do i specify from which test case to retrieve that data?

Comment: Have you seen anything in the log? Do you have any properties in the current test case? It will only show / logs the data if there any properties. Not sure how are you using it? do not have any context. At least show some screenshot. You comments is not helpful either to understand.

Comment: I almost figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest
def testStep = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["3D Secure Call"]
def str = new StringBuilder();
 for (prop in testStep.getPropertyList()){

    if(prop.getName() != "K" && prop.getName() != "RawRequest" && prop.getName() != "Domain" && prop.getName() != "Password" && prop.getName() != "ResponseAsXml" && prop.getName() != "Request" &&  prop.getName() != "RawRequest" && prop.getName() != "Response" && prop.getName() != "Username" && prop.getName() != "Endpoint"){
        str.append(prop.getName() + "=" + testStep.getPropertyValue(prop.getName()) + "&" )

    }
}
str.append("K=1473942615907cuwmviz")
return (MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(str.bytes).encodeHex().toString())
```

I get the string exactly how i wish: M=10000330&PKey=8c124262b3d66f9e47185fd34eec13bbef2acd03170bcf8c284985193bc9a6&a4=50000&a5=EUR&XID=12345678912345678912&K=1473942615907cuwmviz

but now i need to apply the MD5, and i am getting an error. any suggestions?
No such property: bytes for class: java.lang.StringBuilder

Comment: Getting:groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script115.generateMD5_A() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.StringBuilder) values: [M=10000330&PKey=c74737d2a1e27d2efec56cf8148bc6e2b68eac48a8daed17e795421c4acc51&a4=50000&a5=EUR&XID=12345678912345678912&K=1473942615907cuwmviz] Possible solutions: generateMD5_A(java.lang.String) error at line: 14                                    I changed: def generateMD5_A(String s){ MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(s.bytes).encodeHex().toString() }
generateMD5_A(str)