# How to transfer a result to a second method in Groovy (SOAPUI)

Tags: groovy, md5, soapui

I wrote the following script:

```
def testStep = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["3D Secure Call"]
def str = new StringBuilder();
 for (prop in testStep.getPropertyList()){

    if(prop.getName() != "K" && prop.getName() != "RawRequest" && prop.getName() != "Domain" && prop.getName() != "Password" && prop.getName() != "ResponseAsXml" && prop.getName() != "Request" &&  prop.getName() != "RawRequest" && prop.getName() != "Response" && prop.getName() != "Username" && prop.getName() != "Endpoint"){
        str.append(prop.getName() + "=" + testStep.getPropertyValue(prop.getName()) + "&" )

    }
}
str.append("K=1473942615907cuwmviz")
```

And i am getting the following (As expected):
K   M=10000330&PKey=c74737d2a1e27d2efec56cf8148bc6e2b68eac48a8daed17e795421c4acc51&a4=50000&a5=EUR&XID=12345678912345678912&K=1473942615907cuwmviz

Now what i am trying to achieve is sending this string to MD5 hashing function suggested here:

import java.security.MessageDigest

def generateMD5_A(String s){ MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(s.bytes).encodeHex().toString() }

I cannot achieve passing the generated string into this function and getting a new result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You tried `generateMD5_A(str.toString())`

Comment: Duplicate of your other question  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261916/md5-using-groovy-in-soapui

Answer (score 0):

achieved by doing:

def generateMD5_A(String s){ MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(s.bytes).encodeHex().toString() }
generateMD5_A(str.toString());